# What is the meaning of ～はしない?

Tags: grammar

This is actually something I see from time to time :

> もう生きてこの屋敷から出しはしない。

Why is it "出しはしない" instead of "出さない" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「...はしない」 is a stressed form of a negative form of a verb, or it just makes the sentence stronger.

**出さない** means in your sentence *I'll not let you get/go out*, while **出しはしない** means *I'll never let you get/go out*.

Including your 出しはしない, I'll show you some examples as：

> 出｛だ｝す - 出｛だ｝さない - 出｛だ｝しはしない
>   食｛た｝べる - 食｛た｝べない - 食｛た｝べはしない
>   行｛い｝く - 行｛い｝かない - 行｛い｝きはしない
>   見｛み｝る - 見｛み｝ない - 見｛み｝はしない
>   聞｛き｝く - 聞｛き｝かない - 聞｛き｝きはしない
>   話｛はな｝す - 話｛はな｝さない - 話｛はな｝しはしない
>   触｛さわ｝る - 触｛さわ｝らない - 触｛さわ｝りはしない

I'll show you the way to make this kind of expression:

> 1) think of a ます-form of a verb:
>   行く ー> **行き**ます
>   2) omit ます from the ます-form of the verb; which is also called a stem form of the verb:
>   行き
>   3) add はしない to it:
>   行き**はしない** meaning (somebody will) *never go*.

Comment: I see, so this is the "stem" form of a verb plus ～はしない。By "stressed form", you mean that it has the same meaning but it just makes the sentence stronger ?

Comment: @Ushiromiya: That's right. For example, 出さない means in your sentence *I'll **not** let you get/go out*, while 出しはしない means *I'll **never** let you get/go out*.

Comment: I see, I see. Thank you, it was really helpful.